# Why can't I bind these data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, row, rbind

I'm trying to rbind two data frames in R but keep getting a 'duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed' error. They are two data frames with a hundred rows each and the same number of columns. I tried defining the row names before using rbind, but I still get the error. I'm using this:

```
row.names(sons) <- make.names(1:100, unique=TRUE)
row.names(sons2)<-make.names(101:200, unique = TRUE)
sons3 <- rbind(sons, sons2)
```

My data comes from the API of the UK Companies House. Entries in the array look like this:

```
description_identifier                  kind                        title company_type
X1           dissolved-on searchresults#company THIS IS A COMPANY NAME          ltd
                self                                snippet date_of_cessation
X1 /company/08733334 Unit 2, 41 A Road, London, E8  2QH        2015-11-10
                                description date_of_creation company_number company_status
X1 08730034 - Dissolved on 10 November 2015       2013-10-14       08730034      dissolved
```

How can I bind these data frames?

EDIT: as requested, outputs for dput(head(sons)) is

```
structure(list(title = c("SON AND SONS PRODUCTIONS LTD", "SJ AND SONS LTD", 
"DW AND SONS LTD", "PJ AND SONS LTD", "ND AND SONS LTD", "TF AND SONS LTD"
), company_type = c("ltd", "ltd", "ltd", "ltd", "ltd", "ltd"), 
    links = structure(list(self = c("/company/08730034", "/company/08902692", 
    "/company/09211826", "/company/09496249", "/company/09669572", 
    "/company/NI633653")), .Names = "self", row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame"), snippet = c("Unit E1, 41 Dace Road, London, E3  2NG", 
    "17 Poundgate Lane, Westwood Heath, Coventry, CV4 8HJ", "60, Hawkins Road, Folkestone, CT19 4JA", 
    "Dalton House, 9 Dalton Square, Lancaster, LA1 1WD", "19 Barnston Lane, Moreton, Wirral, CH46 7TN", 
    "C/O Rpb Chartered Accountants, 22, St. Colmans Park, Newry, County Down, BT34 2BX"
    ), date_of_cessation = c("2015-11-10", "2015-09-29", "2015-03-17", 
    NA, NA, NA), description = c("08730034 - Dissolved on 10 November 2015", 
    "08902692 - Dissolved on 29 September 2015", "09211826 - Dissolved on 17 March 2015", 
    "09496249 - Incorporated on 18 March 2015", "09669572 - Incorporated on  3 July 2015", 
    "NI633653 - Incorporated on 16 September 2015"), date_of_creation = c("2013-10-14", 
    "2014-02-19", "2014-09-10", "2015-03-18", "2015-07-03", "2015-09-16"
    ), company_number = c("08730034", "08902692", "09211826", 
    "09496249", "09669572", "NI633653"), company_status = c("dissolved", 
    "dissolved", "dissolved", "active", "active", "active")), .Names = c("title", 
"company_type", "links", "snippet", "date_of_cessation", "description", 
"date_of_creation", "company_number", "company_status"), row.names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), class = "data.frame")
```

and for dput(head(sons2)) it's

```
structure(list(title = c("SON AND SONS PRODUCTIONS LTD", "SJ AND SONS LTD", 
"DW AND SONS LTD", "PJ AND SONS LTD", "ND AND SONS LTD", "TF AND SONS LTD"
), company_type = c("ltd", "ltd", "ltd", "ltd", "ltd", "ltd"), 
    links = structure(list(self = c("/company/08730034", "/company/08902692", 
    "/company/09211826", "/company/09496249", "/company/09669572", 
    "/company/NI633653")), .Names = "self", row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame"), snippet = c("Unit E1, 41 Dace Road, London, E3  2NG", 
    "17 Poundgate Lane, Westwood Heath, Coventry, CV4 8HJ", "60, Hawkins Road, Folkestone, CT19 4JA", 
    "Dalton House, 9 Dalton Square, Lancaster, LA1 1WD", "19 Barnston Lane, Moreton, Wirral, CH46 7TN", 
    "C/O Rpb Chartered Accountants, 22, St. Colmans Park, Newry, County Down, BT34 2BX"
    ), date_of_cessation = c("2015-11-10", "2015-09-29", "2015-03-17", 
    NA, NA, NA), description = c("08730034 - Dissolved on 10 November 2015", 
    "08902692 - Dissolved on 29 September 2015", "09211826 - Dissolved on 17 March 2015", 
    "09496249 - Incorporated on 18 March 2015", "09669572 - Incorporated on  3 July 2015", 
    "NI633653 - Incorporated on 16 September 2015"), date_of_creation = c("2013-10-14", 
    "2014-02-19", "2014-09-10", "2015-03-18", "2015-07-03", "2015-09-16"
    ), company_number = c("08730034", "08902692", "09211826", 
    "09496249", "09669572", "NI633653"), company_status = c("dissolved", 
    "dissolved", "dissolved", "active", "active", "active")), .Names = c("title", 
"company_type", "links", "snippet", "date_of_cessation", "description", 
"date_of_creation", "company_number", "company_status"), row.names = c("X101", 
"X102", "X103", "X104", "X105", "X106"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Add the output of `dput(head(sons))` and `dput(head(sons2))` to your question (replace sensitive datas by anything you want before posting)

Comment: Are both `sons` and `sons2` identically structured (i.e., `colnames`)? You say you can't bind them, what does `sons3` look like? (`dput(head(sons3)))`)

Comment: I added the dput outputs. The colnames for both frames are identical. sons3 is empty.

Comment: Those dataframes are in fact perfectly identical. rbind is the wrong strategy. You probably want to figure out how to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your links variable is stored as a data.frame, which is the heart of the problem. To fix this, use the following:

```
sons$links <- as.character(unlist(sons$links))
sons2$links <- as.character(unlist(sons2$links))
```

You may also need to remove the rownames altogether:

```
row.names(sons) <- NULL
row.names(sons2)<- NULL
sons3 <- rbind(sons, sons2)
```

If you want to keep them, then save them as vectors first. In addition,